# Plone: How to customize the RSS view template within ZMI successfully?

Tags: templates, view, rss, customization, plone

I have customized the view for RSS feeds in a Plone site in ZMI/portal_view_customizations.
Just after customizing, the template raises the error

> zope.tal.taldefs.TALError: empty HTML tags cannot use tal:content:
>   u'link, at line 16

I figured out that line 16 declares an empty HTML element and it doesn't make much sense filling it with "tal:content". So I changed from:

```
<link tal:content="feed/link" />
```

to

```
<span tal:content="feed/link">The Link</span>
```

and the template compiles correctly.
But calling the feed on a collection now gives me "insufficient privileges". This happens too if I delete line 16.
Can someone give me a hint on how about to get this working?

For reproduction:

1. On a plone4.3 site, in zmi\portal_view_customizations
2. customize RSS under Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.syndication.ISyndicatable
3. change link tal:content... twice
4. call the feed on the plone site with myplonesite/mycollection/RSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [restricted Python scripts](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/restricted-python-scripts), a TTW-customization via portal_view_customization doesn't work with templates, which calls such methods. You have to write a package to replace the view with your own one.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `myplonesite/mycollection/synPropertiesForm` and Enabling Syndication.
No promises it will work though, RSS seems to require a little bit of effort to get it going.

These links may help:
http://developer.plone.org/functionality/rss.html
http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/RSS-feeds-out-of-Plone-4-td5502707.html

Comment: Basically RSS is enabled and works fine with the standard view template, I'm able to access mycollection/RSS. Only after customizing the view without any changes, I don't have the permission to access it anymore.

Comment: Your first link seems not to be completely up to date, I think CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/rss_template does not exist in plone 4.3 anymore, but thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

Just as additional info I figured out that

- Adding /RSS to a new-style collection invokes the rss.pt of
  plone.app.collection, while the old-style collection uses the RSS.pt of Products.CMFPlone.
- To enable /RSS for other items, either use plone control panel, or for single items
  /synPropertiesForm as Danimal mentioned. These obviously invoke the RSS.pt of
  Products.CMFPlone too.